# select `one` where location = one, all or multiple choices

Tags: mysql, algorithm

I have multiple creatures in database(mysql) and 6 different areas. Currently all creatures appear in everywhere, but I would like to make some appear in one location or multiple selected locations.

The way I would solve it right now is that every location has id from 1 to 9. Graveyard = 1, Swamp = 2, Forest = 3, Caves = 4. Then have it in the creatures table saved as field *where_creature_appears*

```
where
12 appears only in Graveyard and Swamp; 
23 appears only in Swamp and Forest; 
124 appreas only in Graveyard, Swamp, Caves; 
etc
```

and with sql I would use `WHERE LIKE % $location_id %`. If I have more locations then I could extend to letters as well.

Question is would there be better way to do it, or simpler, or smarter. Happy if someone can point in the useful direction with links or ideas.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Do yourself a favor and get familiarized with [database normalisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). Storing multiple values in a single field is always a bad idea. Also read up on [one to many](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-to-many_(data_model)) and [many to many](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_(data_model)) tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by having one more table that would be many-to-many table.

Basically, in that table you will have the information if that creature is in that specific area and the opposite. Because, many creatures can be in many areas, and many areas can have many different creatures.

That table should look like this:

Table name: `creature_area`

```
creature_id | area_id
----------------------
     1      |    2    
     1      |    3    
     3      |    2    
     5      |    1
```

Then, you will be able to query all the areas for the specific creature, and also all the creatures for the specific area, like this:

Give me IDs of all areas for this creature is in:

`SELECT area_id FROM creature_area WHERE creature_id = ....`

Give me IDs of all creatures that are in this area:

`SELECT creature_id FROM creature_area WHERE area_id = ....`

Then you can do all kind of `JOIN`s to get the names of those creature/areas and such.

More details on how to achieve this is here: https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-handle-a-many-to-many-relationship-in-datab

I hope this helps.